# Retrain object detection model with own images (tensorflow)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, image-recognition, training-data

Good morning,

I have been working with the tensorflow [object detection tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) using the [ssd_mobilenet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) they are providing as a frozen graph as well as with the corresponding checkpoint files (*model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001, model.ckpt.index, model.ckpt.meta*).
However, as the images are sometimes badly recognized, I hoped I could feed own images to the detection model and improve its performance for my images, that are all taken by the same camera.

Google could not help me where to start. The questions I am having:
- Are there any code snippets that show which of those files to load and how to train the existing model?
- Do I need to retrain the loaded model with the old data (i.e. COCO) + the new data (my images) or can I just retrain it using my data and the model remembers what it has learned before?

Sorry for this very unspecific questions, but I just can not figure out where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great [walkthrough blog](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) and [code base](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset) written by Dat Tran. He trained a model to recognize Raccoons in images using the pre-trained SSD_mobilenet as a start. This is the best place I found to start. Hope this helps.